# Create an input field with a placeholder that gets written into upon text entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I'm trying to create an input field for a phone number.  I would like the placeholder to show the expected format/pattern: (XXX) XXX-XXXX as shown below.

```
Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="(XXX) XXX-XXXX">
```

However, when the user starts entering numbers, I'd like them to simply replace the individual X's.

After inputting a few numbers the field would look like this (cursor after the 4)...

```
"(302) 4XX-XXXX"
```

And then the user entering backspace would simply replace the last number entered with an X again.  After 2 backspaces...

```
"(30X) XXX-XXXX"
```

I've seen this behavior before in registration forms, but I haven't been able to locate any examples lately.  I was hoping there might be a decent jquery plugin that accomplishes this, but I have not found it yet.

Comment: It's called an input mask. There are definitely plugins for this.

Comment: @crush ... yes, I see that now.  I didn't quite have the right term when searching for it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Mask, with jQuery:

```
jQuery(".maskPhone").mask("(999) 999-99999");
```

You can grab a plugin here: http://jquery-joshbush.googlecode.com/files/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js

Answer (score 1):

The Masked Input Plugin will do what you want. http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use something like the Mask Input plugin in JQuery

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Or

http://digitalbush.com/projects/watermark-input-plugin/.