# input placeholder to be written over

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have an input field for credit card number and I want to achieve a different behaviour from the default place holder.

My place holder is more of a pattern: "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" and I want that in every number entered only the specific x's will be written over and the rest of the placeholder will remain intact(each preserves its own color).

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329687/create-an-input-field-with-a-placeholder-that-gets-written-into-upon-text-entry) which suggests the use of mask and jQuery but I prefer solutions that combines html, css and angular instead.

If it helps there is an illustration:

[image: illustration]

Comment: Have you considered that not all credit cards follow the 4-4-4-4 format?

Comment: Show us your code - we can't know what you mean by default place holder / different behaviour (different from what).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72856713/keep-placeholder-partially-while-typing-in-input-type-text/72856960#72856960

Comment: @OMGDrAcula I did, but the main problem for me is what i have asked.. i believe i can figure out a solution for this problem when needed, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @AndrewAllen the code is a basic input field with an placeholder on it, nothing special

I cant really understand what is it that make you that upset about my question I clarified it in the post, added a link to a post with similar problem(which have more clarification)  and attached a photo... no need to be so toxic

Comment: @daviddavidson asking for code and details is a standard request on this site, not sure why you think I’m upset or how that’s toxic. As answer below, an input mask is one option, another is using the control value accessor to create a custom control e.g. 4 input boxes with auto tab after 4 number inputs.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called an *input mask*. It is unfortunately not a feature of HTML, but you’ll find plenty of libraries and questions on Stackoverflow (:

What is difficult is finding a good one that is

- working with copy & paste or autocomplete
- using number-optimized on-screen keyboards
- not messing up the number when correcting a character in the middle
- works well with assistive technology, which users with disabilities rely on

That’s why credit card inputs that work really well do not use input masks on the web.

Usually their implementation follows this principles:

- The original input is broken apart into inputs and static text (the placeholder)
- Styling is removed from the inputs
- Everything gets wrapped in an element that then is styled like an input
- Text is styled in a way to align flow of static text and input text
- Write a lot of JavaScript to implement behaviour like a single input

Comment: Also, having a different color between the mask and the input might prove to be impossible when working with a single input field. Perhaps some contentEditable magicks might do the trick, but I highly doubt any _existing_ input mask implementations support that level of nitpickery.

Comment: Usually implementations of input masks use several inputs wrapped in something that’s styled as the input.

Comment: @Andy ok I see its not that trivial, I will try to find some mask that suits my case good enough 

thanks for the detailed explanation